# Mocking dates within fastify when running jest tests

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, fastify

I have a fastify server with multiple endpoints and some of the endpoints use `new Date()` for getting the current date.

For the most part I can get the date mocked to (for example) 2023/01/01 using

```js
jest.useFakeTimers({ advanceTimers: true }).setSystemTime(new Date('2023/01/01'))
```

But for some reason this does not work within the fastify server that I am setting up in Jest's `globalSetup`

```js
const mockSetup = async (globalConfig, projectConfig) => {
    const msw = await buildMockServiceWorker()
    const mms = await buildMongoMemoryServer()
    const MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING = mms.getUri() + MONGO_MEMORY_SERVER_MAIN_DB

    process.env = { ...process.env, ...mockEnvVars, MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING }

    const server = await buildServer({ logger: false })
    await server.ready()
    await initializeMongoMemoryServer(server)

    globalThis.server = server
    global.msw = msw
    global.mms = mms
}
```

What is going awry here?